# Python with docker - no such file or directory

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, dockerfile

i'm trying to develop a python application with vscode and docker containers.

Currently i'm using vscode's default dockerfile and when i run it returns this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/spotify-2-mp3\\main.py'
```

This is my dockerfile:

```
# For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python
FROM python

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /app
# Install pip requirements
COPY . .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-configure-containers
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
CMD ["python", "spotify-2-mp3/main.py"]
```

And this is my directory tree:
[image]

Comment: instead of `COPY . .` add this `ADD . /app`

Comment: That error comes just building the images or when using docker-compose? In That case please post also docker-compose.

Comment: @Ashok Since the Dockerfile sets `WORKDIR /app` first, both forms copy to the same directory, and you'd typically prefer `COPY` to `ADD` unless you specifically want to download URLs or unpack archives.  The form in the Dockerfile is fine.

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing where the backslash in the file path in the command string comes from.